Java SQLite, what should I use instead of ORDER BY within an UPDATE query to avoid duplicate key constraint?
I'm currently updating an application which only supports MariaDB as a database in order to also support other database types, such as SQLite. This involves going through each MariaDB method and translating the queries to work with SQLite. I'm not really able to change the structure of the tables within the database too much, since the rest of the code-base is already largely dependent on the specific layout in place.
The database holds information about various different GUIs. The specific tables I'm having problems with both support pagination. Each element within the these tables stores a GuiID, a page number, and a location within the page, which together act as a composite key.



gui_id
page
position
contents




1
0
2
Hello!


1
1
0
Text


1
2
1
More Text


1
3
1
More More Text



The above is a simplified example of what this could look like for one specific gui. There can also be multiple items per page.
The issue arises when trying to implement the insertPage() method and deletePage() method. Here is what the MariaDB implementation looks like for the insert page method:
UPDATE contents SET page = page + 1 WHERE gui_id=? AND page >= ? ORDER BY page DESC
The reverse is also true for the delete page method.
Here, the query needs to use the ORDER BY clause to ensure that the page number is updated from highest to lowest rather than lowest to highest to ensure that there's never a duplicate key error. If it were to increment page numbers the other way around, using the above table as an example, the 3rd row down would conflict with the 4th row down when updating. The same principle applies for the delete page method.
Unfortunately, it doesn't seem that SQLite supports the ORDER BY for use with UPDATE. I'd rather not remove the composite key constraints here, as I'd like to maintain as much parity with the MariaDB implementation as possible.
Two possibly solutions I can think of would be to:
A - Select each row, sort in-code, and then update each row manually within a while loop. Definitely a bad idea, and would be extremely inefficient for larger guis.
B - Create a temporary table to make the changes in and merge it back with the original one. This seems slightly overcomplicated, and I feel like there's probably a simpler solution.
If anyone has any advice, it would be much appreciated.
Edit: I'll update below to explain the duplicate key constraint a bit further with a more "abstracted" table.
Say I have the following data:



page
slot
contents




0
1
text1


0
2
text2


1
1
text3


1
2
text4



In the above example, the columns "page" and "slot" form a unique key constraint when put together. These columns can't ever be duplicate.
Now, I want to insert a new page at the start. The end goal when doing this would look like this:



page
slot
contents




0
1
text5


1
1
text1


1
2
text2


2
1
text3


2
2
text4



As you can see, the "page" column has been incremented by one for all rows, and following this, the new page has been inserted (I've ordered it by page number for clarity's sake).
The SQL statement for this might look like the following: UPDATE pages SET page = page + 1, preceding the insert statement for the new row.
Running this, though, produces a duplicate key error. This is because SQL is going down the table from top to bottom, and reaches a duplicate key constraint when updating the first row down. The page number is incremented, causing it to conflict with the third row down.
With MariaDB, I'm able to overcome this issue by using ORDER BY in the update statement, where I can force it to increment the page number for the highest page number first, meaning no duplicate key error occurs.
This is the functionality I'm looking for with SQLite.
Update: As a final update to this, I've decided to just go ahead and remove the unique key constraints with the SQLite implementation. In theory, it's definitely possible to use temporary tables to accomplish the same functionality, but in an effort to keep maintainability, I've decided not to go with the more complex approach.
I'll keep an eye out for any future answers to this question, as I've still not found a proper solution to the problem.

What does the order by do here? In combination with a LIMIT clause it'd do something, but here, it seems to do nothing, in which case the solution'd be: Simply remove the ORDER BY clause from the UPDATE statement: All elements with gui_id X and a page number Y or higher should get their pagenum incremented by 1.

Perhaps edit the question to include a table with data as it is in your DB now, and the data as it should be, and then ask: "What UPDATE query can I write that will efficiently convert table 1 to table 2 that works on both SQLite and MariaDB?"

@rzwitserloot the ORDER BY clause within the UPDATE statement forces Maria to update rows in a given order. Without doing this, you can run into situations where the page value is incremented to be the same as another item in the following page. I agree it's a bit hard to explain over text, so I'll update my post now with a better example.

Ahhh, okay, the ordering is to ensure mariadb's constraint checker doesn't flip out. I'd expect most engines to figure it out and apply constraint checks to entire statements, not to intermediate steps; in some ways 'make a single SQL statement that does the job on a few completely different SQL engines' is impossible and you have to introduce a flavour selection engine ('if H2 do this, if Maria DB do that, otherwise do a third thing'). Have you looked into MariaDB's constraint rules? Some SQL engines let you set transactions into 'no constraint check' mode, or, 'defer' constraints.

psql for example lets you define a constraint as being deferred. That simply means they are checked as you commit. If you can set the constraint up like that in mariadb, you can simply ditch the order-by clause.

@rzwitserloot Thanks for this. The issue did catch be by surprise at first! Would you mind clarifying slightly further? I'm not really able to change anything relating to the MariaDB implementation, although I'm not sure if that's what you were implying I should do. I've currently got the MariaDB implementation and the SQLite implementation divided into separate classes, both implementing the same interface.

The MariaDB implementation is working fine as-is, as I don't plan on changing the query for that. I'm instead looking for an alternative query which I can use within the SQLite class. Thanks!

Well, as per the django docs, 'deferred constraints are ignored on MySQL, MariaDB and SQLite because they do not support them' so there goes that. See also this question.

Thanks @rzwitserloot. I think the best solution then will be to create a temporary table to execute the query on, and then merge it back with the original. Thanks for your help.
